# Iteratively print plots in R

Tags: r, graph

I have a series of vectors and I want to print them iteratively (so far i did it hardcoding it but i want to avoid doing it one by one again). 
the names of the variables that hold the names of the vectors are stored in "genes" (char), while i can see the variables using ls() (ok nothing new so far)
each vector is of variable length and i want to print the index (x axis) against the value (y axis). 
the data i'm downloading come from the TCGA database and can be accessible with their R package.
what i have so far is:

```
library(cgdsr)

#create object

mycgds = CGDS("http://www.cbioportal.org/public-portal/")
genes <- c("AGPAT1", "CDIPT", "CDS1", "CEL", "CEPT1", "DGKA", "LCAT", "LCLAT1", "LPCAT3", "LPIN1", "LPL", "MOGAT3", "PEMT", "PISD", "PLA2G4B", "PLD1","PTDSS1", "PTDSS2", "ATX", "PLA2") # list of my gene names

# get z score about these genes for kidney cancer
data <- getProfileData(mycgds, genes, "kirc_tcga_pub_rna_seq_v2_mrna_median_Zscores", "kirc_tcga_pub_3way_complete" )

data <- t(data)

#set z-value cutoff (equivalent to p<0.05)
i <- -1.96
j <- 1.96

# select only samples that have values lower than i and higher than j

AGPAT1 <- data[1,which(data[1,] < i | data[1,] > j)]
CDIPT <- data[2,which(data[2,] < i | data[2,] > j)]
CDS1 <- data[3,which(data[3,] < i | data[3,] > j)]
CEL <- data[4,which(data[4,] < i | data[4,] > j)]
CEPT1 <- data[5,which(data[5,] < i | data[5,] > j)]
DGKA <- data[6,which(data[6,] < i | data[6,] > j)]
LCAT <- data[7,which(data[7,] < i | data[7,] > j)]
LCLAT1 <- data[8,which(data[8,] < i | data[8,] > j)]
LPCAT3 <- data[9,which(data[9,] < i | data[9,] > j)]
LPIN1 <- data[10,which(data[10,] < i | data[10,] > j)]
LPL <- data[11,which(data[11,] < i | data[11,] > j)]
MOGAT3 <- data[12,which(data[12,] < i | data[12,] > j)]
PEMT <- data[13,which(data[13,] < i | data[13,] > j)]
PISD <- data[14,which(data[14,] < i | data[14,] > j)]
PLA2G4B <- data[15,which(data[15,] < i | data[15,] > j)]
PLD1 <- data[16,which(data[16,] < i | data[16,] > j)]
PTDSS1 <- data[17,which(data[17,] < i | data[17,] > j)]
PTDSS2 <- data[18,which(data[18,] < i | data[18,] > j)]
ATX <- data[19,which(data[19,] < i | data[19,] > j)]
PLA2 <- data[20,which(data[20,] < i | data[20,] > j)]

#setup page for the 18graphs, not 20 cause there are no values for the last two
 par(mfrow= c(3,6)) 

   color <- function(x){
      ifelse(x > 1.96, "red", "green")
    }

    for (k in seq(1,length(ls()),1)) #iterate through ls()
      for(z in seq(1, length(genes),1)) #iterate through my list of genes
        if(genes[z] == ls()[k]) #if they match print them out
          plot(ls()[k], pch=15, col=color(ls()[k]), main =genes[z], ylim=c(-3,30))
```

the "color" function is to assign a color based on the value

however, i can't get this to work. it does not print the all the graphs but just a few and it does not apply the right colors.

thanks :)

Comment: Besides that your code doens't run, for example in `plot(ls()[k]), pch=15, col=color(ls()[k]), main =genes[z], ylim=c(-3,30))` there is an additional `)` after `plot(ls()[k]`, could you please be clearer maybe with some reproducible example?

Comment: the extra `)` is just a typo when i copied/pasted it cause i tried to modify it before posting it. i'm gonna add more info on top, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, easy. You missied `get()`. Try

```
for (k in seq(1,length(ls()),1)) #iterate through ls()
  for(z in seq(1, length(genes),1)) #iterate through my list of genes
    if(genes[z] == ls()[k]) #if they match print them out
      plot(get(ls()[k]), pch=15, col=color(ls()[k]), main =genes[z], ylim=c(-3,30))
```

Not related to your exact question but here is a clearer (and faster) version of your loop

```
for (k in 1:length(ls())) #iterate through ls()
    if(any(geneFound <- genes == ls()[k])) #if they match print them out
      plot(get(ls()[k]), pch=15, col=color(ls()[k]), main =genes[geneFound],
           ylim=c(-3,30))
```

EDIT:

After changing the `col=color(ls()[k])` in `col=color(get(ls()[k]))` I got this:

[image]

And this error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

due to the two missing vectors you said. Is it what you expect?

Comment: thanks for the `get()` hint, now it prints the graphs. however, i cannot get the correct colors. with the previous code i get all red dots, if i use `mean(x)` i don't get any dots.

Comment: `col=color(get(ls()[k]))` :-) . Happy?

Comment: also... when i harcoded it i used `plot(AGPAT1, pch=15, col=color(AGPAT1), main ="AGPAT1 ", ylim=c(-3,30))` and this gives me the correct colors...i tried `col=color(get(ls()[k]))`, it gives me the correct colors but i don't understand why it does not print all the graphs but only a few..and if i re-run the script now i don't get any...RStudio bug?!?

Comment: I did a mistake, if you want any single point below 1.96 to be green, remove `mean` from `ifelse` cause the latter is a vectorized function and will give you the right colour for each point. Sorry about that

Comment: yes, i think one or two of the genes in the list have no data. however,there are still a few genes missing from the graphs and i realized there is a problem with the indexing of gene names. the `row.names(data)` are organized alphabetically, and not like those in `genes` so the order is not correct when i call i.e. `which(data[1,])`. i'm writing now a function to work around it. thanks for all the help tho, it really helped me clarifying the ideas :)

Comment: i can't upvote yet, i only have 3 reputations..working on it ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to produce these kinds of groups of plots, I would really recommend switching to `ggplot2` (or `lattice`). This has the `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` options that take care of this kind of thing. Without a reproducible example from your side it is hard to give more than an example from the `ggplot2` user docs:

```
p <- qplot(price, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 1000)
p + facet_wrap(~ color)
```

[image]